# Convert If rewrite rule to modrewrite

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, mod-rewrite

Please help me to convert below to a modrewrite rule.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'm-dev.domain.com'">
 Redirect "/subdomain/page-to-load" "http://m-dev.domain.com/subdomain/page-to-load-mobile"
</If>
```

If wont work on apche 2.2 hence I need to use mod rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m-dev.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/?subdomain/page-to-load$ /subdomain/page-to-load-mobile [L,R=permanent]
```